# How to create a lookup column with Site Design for modern sites

Tags: lookup-column, column, site-design

As per the [MS article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview) i have created site design file and uploaded to SharePoint which is working fine. But I want to create a lookup column with the site design approach. I am using below code to create lookup column but it is failing where I have done the mistake?

```
{
    "verb":"addSPFieldXml",
    "schemaXml":"<Field ID=\"{da94e56b-428f-4b95-b4c6-24aed0256475}\" Name=\"Trainings\" StaticName=\"Test_x0020_Lookup_x0020_Column\" DisplayName=\"Training\" Type=\"Lookup\" Required=\"FALSE\" List=\"Lists/Trainings\" ShowField=\"Title\" PrependId=\"FALSE\" />"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When site designs were introduced, certain field types were not available, among them Taxonomy and Lookups. Assuming that's still the case, you can't do it.

A potential workaround: You can invoke a Flow in a site design. You can have your Flow call an Azure Function to add the functionality you need via code.

Comment: It is not possible to add through SPFx also. I mean provisioning assets through SPFx

Comment: But no where it was mentioned that looks are not supported. How I can prove, that currently lookups are not supported